# Can filters be created based on categories?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-categories

Originally, I was using POP to access one Gmail account from another.  I'd really like to have only the emails from the Primary category of the second account be downloaded to the first account, but this does not seem to be possible.

So, instead, I'm trying to forward emails from the second Gmail account to the first based on the same set of criteria (`category:Primary`), but the filters don't seem to have a parameter to designate this.

Is there a way to add this category information into a filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think `category:primary` would work. You'd put that in the "Has the words" field.

(I just tried it, and it seems to work.)

If that doesn't work for you, there's only a few categories, so you could always try negation.

```
-category:updates, -category:social, -category:forums, -category:promotions
```

In other words, *not* one of the other categories.

Comment: Thanks, it was the "Has the words" part that was unintuitive to me.